# Remove fieldset boarder and box-shadow from legend element

Tags: css, html, legend, fieldset

I am trying to remove the background lines and shadows from the area where my legend is. Once I set the background to transparent in the legends property I can still see the lines.  My code is as follows

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>text goes here</legend>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
        margin:20px;
        padding:0 10px 10px;
        border:1px solid #666;
        border-radius:10px;
        box-shadow:0 0 10px #666;
        padding-top:10px;
 }  
 legend {
     margin: 0px 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     background: transparent ; 
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 2em;
 }
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
fieldset {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `border` and `box-shadow` are on the `fieldset`. Just add the following and it should work:

```
fieldset{
   border:0;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: I need the border and shadow-box to remain around the rest of the fieldset, just not where the legend is.