# Removing white background from control panel in leaflet map using R

Tags: r, leaflet

So I'm trying to add a north arrow in my leaflet map (using `R`). I thought of using the `addControl` function to simply add a `.png` file of a north arrow which works fine but I'm not a huge fan of the white background I get around the arrow.

Is there any way of removing this and displaying just the arrow?

Comment: North is always up in web mercator. Why add a north arrow?

Comment: I'm also using the map in a printed document and there I need it. I know I could have just put it in manually but that's messy and I wanted to figure out how I can do it in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

After reading [Remove fieldset boarder and box-shadow from legend element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529312/remove-fieldset-boarder-and-box-shadow-from-legend-element), you need to set the [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) property within the [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) element to zero using [css](/questions/tagged/css).

You supply this information within the `className` argument within the [`addControl()`](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/R/controls.R) function.

[image: SS of Leaflet Map with Clear North Arrow Icon]

```
# load necessary packages
library( leaflet )

# north arrow icon url
north.arrow.icon <- 
  "<img src='http://ian.umces.edu/imagelibrary/albums/userpics/10002/normal_ian-symbol-north-arrow-2.png' style='width:40px;height:60px;'>"

# make map
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView( lng = -87.567215
           , lat = 41.822582
           , zoom = 11 ) %>%
  setMaxBounds( lng1 = -87.94011
                , lat1 = 41.64454
                , lng2 = -87.52414
                , lat2 = 42.02304 ) %>%
  addControl( html = north.arrow.icon
              , position = "bottomleft"
              , className = "fieldset {
    border: 0;
}")

# end of script #
```

Comment: @Anomise no problem! Could you do me a favor? Would you mind accepting my post so that it marks this question as solved? I would appreciate it a lot! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done! And thanks again. I'm pretty new to this so I really appreciate any help I can get.